# How to filter tables in databases in kafka jdbc connect source

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, mysql-connector, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using Kafka Connect in Confluent Community Platform to keep MySQL databases synchronized. Sources and sinks are MySQL databases. It didn't work.

There are some issues in my situations:

1. There are tables in other databases in the same server, and i don't want to read them into Kafka, but Kafka Connect Source keep trying to read other databases.
2. I want to use `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` in both Source Connector and Sink Connector, but sink connectors couldn't insert correctly.
3. I want to synchronize several databases, tables in different databases may be with same table names, how to avoid table names conflict and sink connectors 
   route the Kafka topics correctly to insert data into the right databases?  [MySQL Synchronization illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKGqJ.png)

The Kafka JDBC Source Connector config file is:

```
{
       "name": "br-auths-3910472223-source",
       "config": {
       "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",

       "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
       "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
       "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",

"tasks.max": "1",
"connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/br_auths?user=root&password=123456",
"database.whitelist":"br_auths",
"table.blacklist": "br_auths.__migrationversions,br_auths.auths_service_apps",

"mode": "timestamp",
"timestamp.column.name": "utime",
"validate.non.null": "false",

"incrementing.column.name": "id",
"topic.prefix": "br_auths__"
}
}
```

The Kafka JDBC Sink Connector config file is:

```
{
"name": "br-auths-3910472223-sink",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",

    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",

    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://rm-hp303a0n2vr8970.mysql.huhehaote.rds.aliyuncs.com:3306/dev-br-auths-391047222?user=br_auths&password=@123456",

    "topics": "br_auths__auths_roles,br_auths__auths_user_logins,br_auths__auths_user_roles,br_auths__auths_users,br_auths__auths_user_claims,br_auths__auths_user_tokens,br_auths__auths_role_claims", 

    "auto.create": "true",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",

    "transforms":"dropTopicPrefix",
    "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.regex":"br_auths__(.*)",
    "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.replacement":"$1" 
}
}
```

I want to create several pairs of source and sink connectors for different databases, some white list tables in the database A in MySQL server-A can be synchronized with database A in MySQL server-B incrementally.

Update 1:

I changed to connect-avro-distributed, Debezium Source Connector and JDBC Sink Connector. The source connector is:

```
{
   "name":"br-auths-3910472223-source",
   "config":{
       "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
       "tasks.max": "1",
       "database.hostname": "localhost",
       "database.port": "3306",
       "database.user": "root",
       "database.password": "br123456",
       "database.useLegacyDatetimeCode": "false",
       "database.server.id": "184",
       "database.server.name": "local3910472223",
       "database.whitelist":"br_auths",
       "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
       "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.br-auths.local3910472223" ,
       "table.blacklist": "br_auths.__migrationversions,br_auths.auths_service_apps",
       "include.schema.changes": "true",
       "transforms": "route,TimestampConverter",
       "transforms.TimestampConverter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",  
       "transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type": "string", 
       "transforms.TimestampConverter.field": "payload.after.ctime", 
       "transforms.TimestampConverter.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
       "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
       "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
       "transforms.route.replacement": "$2__$3"  
    }
}
```

And the sink connector is:

```
{
"name": "br-auths-3910472223-sink",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://rm-hp303a0n2.mysql.huhehaote.rds.aliyuncs.com:3306/dev-br-auths-391047222?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&user=br_auths&password=123456",
    "dialect.name": "MySqlDatabaseDialect",
    "topics.regex": "br_auths__(.*)",        
    "transforms": "dropTopicPrefix,unwrap",
    "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.regex":"br_auths__(.*)",
    "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.replacement":"$1",        
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "pk.fields": "Id",
    "pk.mode": "record_value"
    }
}
```

The Avro message transforms into json like this:

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "Id"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "UserId"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "RoleId"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "APPID"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": false,
                        "default": 0,
                        "field": "IsDeleted"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp",
                        "version": 1,
                        "default": 0,
                        "field": "ctime"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp",
                        "version": 1,
                        "default": 0,
                        "field": "utime"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": true,
                "name": "local3910472223.br_auths.auths_user_roles.Value",
                "field": "before"
            },
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "Id"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "UserId"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "RoleId"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "APPID"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": false,
                        "default": 0,
                        "field": "IsDeleted"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp",
                        "version": 1,
                        "default": 0,
                        "field": "ctime"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "name": "io.debezium.time.Timestamp",
                        "version": 1,
                        "default": 0,
                        "field": "utime"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": true,
                "name": "local3910472223.br_auths.auths_user_roles.Value",
                "field": "after"
            },
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "version"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "name"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "server_id"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "ts_sec"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "gtid"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "file"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "pos"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "row"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "optional": true,
                        "default": false,
                        "field": "snapshot"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "thread"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "db"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "table"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "query"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": false,
                "name": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.Source",
                "field": "source"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": false,
                "field": "op"
            },
            {
                "type": "int64",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "ts_ms"
            }
        ],
        "optional": false,
        "name": "local3910472223.br_auths.auths_user_roles.Envelope"
    },
    "payload": {
        "before": null,
        "after": {
            "Id": "DB4DA841364860D112C3C76BDCB36635",
            "UserId": "0000000000",
            "RoleId": "5b7e5f9b4bc00d89c4cf96ae",
            "APPID": "br.region2",
            "IsDeleted": 0,
            "ctime": 1550138524000,
            "utime": 1550138524000
        },
        "source": {
            "version": "0.8.3.Final",
            "name": "local3910472223",
            "server_id": 0,
            "ts_sec": 0,
            "gtid": null,
            "file": "mysql-bin.000003",
            "pos": 64606,
            "row": 0,
            "snapshot": true,
            "thread": null,
            "db": "br_auths",
            "table": "auths_user_roles",
            "query": null
        },
        "op": "c",
        "ts_ms": 1550568556614
    }
}
```

The columns using MySQL datetime type were serialized to a big integer, the JDBC sink connector tried to insert into MySQL datetime columns and it failed.

So I wrote `transforms.TimestampConverter` in the source connect config, but the ctime, utime columns didn't change. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to keep your databases in sync, the JDBC Source connector is not the best - you want to use proper log-based CDC, which for MySQL you can get with Debezium. More details [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc).
2. If you're not doing anything else with the data, do you even need Kafka? Would a dedicated MySQL replication tool be more appropriate?
3. To your specific problems. [This article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-jdbc-source-connector-deep-dive) will address a lot of your questions. In particular:

   1. > There are tables in other databases in the same server, and i don't want to read them into Kafka, but Kafka Connect Source keep trying to read other databases.

      Use a combination of `table.whitelist`, `table.blacklist`, and `schema.pattern` as required. If you can't match the entire pattern with one connector you'll need to use multiple connectors to achieve the desired set.
   2. > I want to use org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter in both Source Connector and Sink Connector, but sink connectors couldn't insert correctly.

      Without you explaining "couldn't insert correctly" it's hard to answer this. In general, I would use Avro because of the richer schema support and more efficient messages (no embedded schema, schema is stored in Schema Registry). See [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained) for more details.
   3. > I want to synchronize several databases, tables in different databases may be with same table names, how to avoid table names conflict and sink connectors route the Kafka topics correctly to insert data into the right databases?

      You will want to use a combination of `topic.prefix` on the Source connector to tag topics from a particular source, and then Single Message Transform `RegexRouter` (as you've already found) to manipulate the topic names further, either in the source connector and/or the sink connector. You might need multiple sink connectors using a `topics.regex` to pick particular topics to route to a particular database.

Comment: Is it really Mr. Robin Moffatt? I read all your articles then I choose this solution. Now I updated my codes, use Debezium Avro serialization and JDBC sink. I used transform route in debezium source connector and topic.regex, dropTopicPrefix to handle multiple databases with same table names. But now I cannot handle the timestamp problem, maybe a SMT can help. I tried to write transforms like [link](https://gist.github.com/rmoff/179ed4067b9f042344cf597286ac1840) but didn't work.

Comment: 2. I uploaded an image to show the purpose of my project ![img](https://bzgsoft.blob.core.chinacloudapi.cn/publics/blogs/MySQL-Data-Synchonization-with-Kafka-Connect.jpg)